# kafka connect hdfs sink connector is failing even when json data contains schema and payload field

Tags: apache-kafka, hdfs, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying kafka connect hdfs sink connector for moving json data from kafka to hdfs.

Even when the json data in kafka has schema and payload kafka connect task is failing with error

```
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: JsonConverter with schemas.enable requires \"schema\" and \"payload\" fields and may not contain additional fields.
```

**Data in Kafka:**

./bin/kafka-console-consumer --topic test_hdfs_json_schema_payload_1 --zookeeper localhost:2181 --from-beginning

```
{"schema": {"type": "struct","fields": [{"type": "string","optional": false,"field": "Name"}, {"type": "string","optional": false,"field": "company"}],"optional": false,"name": "Person"},"payload": {"Name": "deepak","company": "BT"}}
{"schema": {"type": "struct","fields": [{"type": "string","optional": false,"field": "Name"}, {"type": "string","optional": false,"field": "company"}],"optional": false,"name": "Person"},"payload": {"Name": "sufi","company": "BT"}}
{"schema": {"type": "struct","fields": [{"type": "string","optional": false,"field": "Name"}, {"type": "string","optional": false,"field": "company"}],"optional": false,"name": "Person"},"payload": {"Name": "vikas","company": "BT"}}
```

**submitted HDFS sink job using below command:**

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{"name": "connect-cluster-15may-308pm", "config": {"connector.class":"io.confluent.connect.hdfs.HdfsSinkConnector", "tasks.max":"2", "hdfs.url": "hdfs://localhost:9000","flush.size": "1","topics":"test_hdfs_json_schema_payload_1","topics.dir":"/deepak/kafka-connect/trial1"}}' http://localhost:8083/connectors
```

**distributed kafka connect worker configuration:**

```
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
key.converter.schemas.enable=true
value.converter.schemas.enable=true
```

**error message:**

http://localhost:8083/connectors/connect-cluster-15may-308pm/tasks/0/status

```
{
    "state": "FAILED",
    "trace": "org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: JsonConverter with schemas.enable requires \"schema\" and \"payload\" fields and may not contain additional fields. If you are trying to deserialize plain JSON data, set schemas.enable=false in your converter configuration.\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter.toConnectData(JsonConverter.java:309)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:400)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:249)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:179)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:148)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:139)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:182)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)\n",
    "id": 0,
    "worker_id": "127.0.0.1:8083"
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What version of Kafka Connect are you using? It helps to know this when working from the stacktrace to determine the source of the error.

I think what's happening is that you have data in the values, but not in the keys. Since you have both `key.converter` and `value.converter` set to the `JsonConverter` and with `schemas.enable=true`, it is expecting to see the envelope format containing `schema` and `payload` for both. However, I'm guessing your keys are all `null`.

This is sort of the reverse problem as https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-3832 where `JsonConverter` never generates true `null` values. Instead it always generates the envelope containing the expected optional schema + a `null` payload. In this case, converting from Kafka to Connect's data API isn't working since it is expecting the same envelope format in the keys.

You can verify this is the problem by adding `--property print.key=true` to your console consumer command. If it is printing out `null` keys, the problem is that the JsonConverter cannot decode them.

An easy workaround is to just use some other `Converter` for keys that doesn't care about `null` values -- there's no data in the keys anyway. One that ships with Kafka Connect is `org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter`.

Comment: I am using  version 3.2.1. you are correct the issue was with null key. it worked when i changed key converter to  org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter. But when i made  schemas.enable=false and used JsonConverter  for both key and value converter there is no output generated in HDFS at the same time I don't see any error message in the log.